# RxJava propogate error from onError to parent from callback

Tags: java, callback, rx-java2

I am trying to propagate error from `onError` to parent caller from `Observable`.
I am always getting `UndeliverableException` and control is not getting back to my parent. What can be done to get control over to parent?

```java
public class TestClass {

    public void process() {
        try {
            test();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Want control here if something goes wrong
        }
    }

    private void test() {
        // observable is defined before below call
        observable.subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Demo>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(Demo t) {
                // Exception occured here
                throw new CustomRunTimeException("Some Exception"); 
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // I receive CustomRunTimeException here
                // how to propagate to caller?
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In reactive programming, signals are not tied to the "parent method" and unless you are willing to block it (for example, `blockingSubscribe`), there is no way to get back to it.

Comment: I  am fine with blocking. But what should be done programmatically in order to do this?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingForEach-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @akarnokd, I have used blocking subscribe while defining observable. Now, I am able to receive the control back after callback.

`observable.blockingSubscribe();`